# Sql server query for numbers inside a square bracket

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I have few formats of records in a table, `ABCDEF`, `[123]ABCDEF`, `ABCDEF[ABC]` and `ABCDEF[123]` Numbers of letters and digits are not fixed, they vary.

I can easily find the ones with brackets by something like this and it's variations.

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y LIKE '%/[%' ESCAPE '/'
```

But I want to find the records where there are only three numbers inside the brackets and only if they appear at the beginning or ending of the line. i.e  `[123]ABCDEF` and `ABCDEF[123]` formats.

I tried `LIKE '%[___/]' ESCAPE '/'` and hoped to manipulate it only accepting numbers inside the bracket but wasn't able to make it work.

A huge caveat is there might be records such as `ABC[123]DEF` format. This might troublesome because I don't want such records returned. I don't know if there are such records but I can't dismiss the possibility.

How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "..but wasn't able to make it work."    Why not?   What error did you get?   It sounds like you're describing Larnu's solution, but without seeing your code, we can't explain why it didn't work for you.

Comment: @TabAlleman No, it's not what Larnu provide. The OP clearly say in _the middle_ or _the end_ of the string.

Comment: @Sami you're right, I didn't read the question that way at first.   It is still the case, however, that Ege hasn't posted the code that didn't work for him/her, which makes it difficult to help debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets are used to provide valid set of characters. `[0-9]` means any digit from 0 to 9. If bracket is used literally, it must be escaped:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(T nvarchar(20))

INSERT @t values ('ABCDEF'), ('[123]ABCDEF'), ('ABCDEF[ABC]'), ('ABCDEF[123]'), ('AS[123]AS')

SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE T LIKE '\[[0-9][0-9][0-9]\]%' ESCAPE '\'
   OR T LIKE '%\[[0-9][0-9][0-9]\]' ESCAPE '\'

--Or match anywhere
--WHERE T LIKE '%\[[0-9][0-9][0-9]\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

**Result**

```
T
--------------------
[123]ABCDEF
ABCDEF[123]
```